# Extended tracking in unity using vuforia model target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have an issue in unity where I am struggling to enable extended tracking. I have a 3D object that augments when the real object is found. The issue is that the 3D object that has been augmented does not stay on the screen, but disappears. I would like the model target to stay on the screen after it has been augmented. How do I do this?

Answer (score -2):

Check the inspector of the target you want to track, there you will find in the (Image targe behaviour>Advanced) tab, the toogle option to enable the extended tracking.

Unity screenshot

[image]

It should be as simple as that.

Review[Vuforia website](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking) for more information of extended tracking.

Comment: The issue was related to the model target generator not image target.